# Bad performance While training Lstm for Text Classification on Amazon Fine Food Reviews Dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, text-classification

I am trying to train a Lstm model for Text classification on Amazon Fine food review problem , I am using same dataset as provided by kaggle , I am using tokenizer to convert text data into tokens , but while I am training I am getting same accuracy for all the epochs .Like this

```
Epoch 1/5
55440/55440 [==============================] - 161s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3666 - acc: 0.8516 - val_loss: 2.3741 - val_acc: 0.8511
Epoch 2/5
55440/55440 [==============================] - 159s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3666 - acc: 0.8516 - val_loss: 2.3741 - val_acc: 0.8511
Epoch 3/5
55440/55440 [==============================] - 160s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3666 - acc: 0.8516 - val_loss: 2.3741 - val_acc: 0.8511
Epoch 4/5
55440/55440 [==============================] - 160s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3666 - acc: 0.8516 - val_loss: 2.3741 - val_acc: 0.8511
```

Moreover when I am plotting my confusion matrix None of the Negative classes are predicted only positive classes are predicted.
I think I am mostly doing wrong when converting Labels i.e. 'Positive' and 'Negative' to some numerical representation for classification.
Please see my code for more details.

I have tried increasing number of Lstm units and epochs also tried increasing length of sequences but none worked , please note that I have done all pre-processing on reviews as required.

```
# train and test split x is dataframe consisting of amazon fine food review 
#dataset
x = df
x1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
y = df['Score']
x1.head()
import math
train_pct_index = int(0.70 * len(df)) #train data size = 70%
X_train, X_test = x1[:train_pct_index], x1[train_pct_index:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_pct_index], y[train_pct_index:]
#y_test.value_counts()
x1_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
x2_df = pd.DataFrame(X_test)



from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_train=encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test=encoder.fit_transform(y_test)

# tokenizing reviews 
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5000 )
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x1_df['CleanedText'])

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x1_df['CleanedText'])
test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x2_df['CleanedText'])

train_data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=500)


test_data = pad_sequences(test_sequences, maxlen=500)

nb_words = (np.max(train_data) + 1)

# building lstm model and compiling it
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_words,50,input_length=500))
model.add(LSTM(20))


model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I would like my lstm model to generalise well and predict negative reviews which are minority class in this case as well.

Comment: Try change Dense(1, activation='softmax') to Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') since your output can be either positive or negative. For softmax case, output neurone should be Dense(2, activation='softmax').